Issue with Transformer-based Chatbot Generating Incoherent answers
I'm developing a chatbot using Hugging Face's transformers library. The bot is supposed to detect the input language (Spanish, Catalan, or English) and respond accordingly using pre-trained models. However, the responses are often incoherent or contain repeated characters.
Here is the project structure:
pythonAI/
├── download.py
├── learner.py
├── main.py
├── model_old.py
├── modelos
│   ├── ca
│   │   ├── config.json
│   │   ├── generation_config.json
│   │   ├── merges.txt
│   │   ├── model.safetensors
│   │   ├── special_tokens_map.json
│   │   ├── tokenizer_config.json
│   │   ├── tokenizer.json
│   │   └── vocab.json
│   ├── en
│   │   ├── config.json
│   │   ├── generation_config.json
│   │   ├── merges.txt
│   │   ├── model.safetensors
│   │   ├── special_tokens_map.json
│   │   ├── tokenizer_config.json
│   │   ├── tokenizer.json
│   │   └── vocab.json
│   └── es
│       ├── config.json
│       ├── generation_config.json
│       ├── model.safetensors
│       ├── special_tokens_map.json
│       ├── tokenizer_config.json
│       ├── tokenizer.json
│       └── vocab.txt
├── model.py
├── nlp_processor.py
├── __pycache__
│   ├── learner.cpython-39.pyc
│   ├── model.cpython-39.pyc
│   ├── nlp_processor.cpython-39.pyc
│   └── search_engine.cpython-39.pyc
├── README.md
├── search_engine.py
└── utils.py

Here is the relevant code:
nlp_processor.py for language detection and text preprocessing:
from langdetect import detect
import re

def detect_language(text):
    try:
        return detect(text)
    except:
        return 'unknown'

def preprocess_text(text):
    text = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', text).strip()
    return text

model.py for loading models and generating responses:
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer

class ChatModel:
    def __init__(self):
        self.models = {
            'es': self.load_model('./modelos/es'),
            'ca': self.load_model('./modelos/ca'),
            'en': self.load_model('./modelos/en')
        }
    
    def load_model(self, model_path):
        model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_path)
        tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_path)
        return model, tokenizer
    
    def get_response(self, processed_input, lang):
        model, tokenizer = self.models.get(lang, (None, None))
        if model is None or tokenizer is None:
            return "Estoy aprendiendo, pronto podré hablar en tu idioma. Escríbeme en Español, catalán o inglés."
        
        inputs = tokenizer.encode(processed_input, return_tensors='pt')
        outputs = model.generate(inputs, max_length=50, num_return_sequences=1, pad_token_id=tokenizer.eos_token_id)
        response = tokenizer.decode(outputs[0], skip_special_tokens=True)
        return response

main.py for coordinating the chatbot:
from nlp_processor import detect_language, preprocess_text
from model import ChatModel

def main():
    chat_model = ChatModel()
    
    while True:
        user_input = input("Pregunta: ")
        if user_input.lower() in ['salir', 'exit', 'quit']:
            break
        
        detected_lang = detect_language(user_input)
        if detected_lang not in ['es', 'ca', 'en']:
            detected_lang = 'unknown'
        
        processed_input = preprocess_text(user_input)
        response = chat_model.get_response(processed_input, detected_lang)
        
        print(f"Chatbot: {response}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Example issue:
When I input "¿hombre o mujer?" the chatbot answers with:
Chatbot: ¿ hombre o mujer? ¿ ¿ ¿ ¿ ¿ ¿ ¿ ¿ ¿ ¿ ¿ ¿ ¿ ¿ ¿ ¿ ¿ ¿ ¿ ¿ ¿ ¿ ¿ ¿ ¿ ¿ ¿ ¿ ¿ ¿ ¿ ¿ ¿ ¿ ¿ ¿ ¿ ¿ ¿ ¿ ¿ ¿ ¿ ¿ ¿ ¿ ¿ ¿ ¿ ¿ ¿ ¿ ¿ ¿lo??????????????????????????????????????

I've ensured that the models are correctly downloaded and placed in the appropriate directories.
What could be causing this issue, and how can I fix it?
Thank you for your help!
Here are the specific issues I'm facing:
Responses are often incoherent.
Responses contain repeated characters or punctuation.
Steps I've taken:
Verified the integrity of the model files.
Checked the versions of transformers, torch, and other dependencies.
Ensured that the tokenizers are correctly paired with their respective models.
Environment:
Python 3.9
transformers 4.12.5
torch 1.10.0
langdetect 1.0.9
I'm looking for organic answers

Few of the possible causes might be :
The way the model's output is being decoded (converted back into text) is causing the repetition of characters and punctuation. This could be due to incorrect parameters in the tokenizer.decode function or issues with the tokenizer itself.
OR
model gets "stuck" in a loop, generating the same tokens repeatedly.
I guess below code can be taken for reference:
def get_response(self, processed_input, lang):
# ... (same model and tokenizer loading logic)
inputs = tokenizer.encode(processed_input, return_tensors='pt')
outputs = model.generate(
    inputs, 
    max_length=80,             # Increased max length
    num_return_sequences=1, 
    pad_token_id=tokenizer.eos_token_id,
    temperature=0.7,           # Adjusted temperature
    repetition_penalty=1.1,    # Adjusted repetition penalty
    do_sample=True              # Enables sampling for more diverse responses
)

response = tokenizer.decode(outputs[0], skip_special_tokens=True)

# Remove everything after the EOS token
eos_token = tokenizer.eos_token or '<|endoftext|>'
response = response.split(eos_token)[0].strip()

return response

